# Power State for Softlayer Servers

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I wanted to see if there is a difference between a "powered down but connected" and a "Powered down disconnected" state. I am currently working on the API integration and from what I can tell there is no fundamental difference that I can see.

Comment: Your question is quite vague.  You may want to modify it to get a better response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the image for connected means that the monitoring for service ping is UP (you can check that in the monitoring tab). I do not know what you wnat to do, but using the API there are methods to know if the machine is power down or power on, and there is another method to review the status of the monitoring services.

Regards

Comment: Thank you Nelson! I was just checking to see if there was specific state that the servers needed to be in.